# Ошибки BindingResult не показываются на странице через Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Вот мой пост метод

```
    @PostMapping
public String saveOrder(@Valid @ModelAttribute OrderCreationDto order,
                        BindingResult bindingResult,
                        @AuthenticationPrincipal AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser,
                        Model model) {
    System.out.println("BINDING " + bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        fillMenuModelWithData(model);
        return "menu";
    }


    try {
        orderService.saveOrder(order, authenticatedUser);
    } catch (InsufficientFundsException e) {
        log.debug(e.toString());
        fillMenuModelWithData(model);
        return "menu";
    }
    return "redirect:/orders/history";
}
```

А это helper метод, просто заполняет аттрибутами страницу ( нужны для правильной работы ссылок на странице, они берут эти аттрибуты ).

```
    private void fillMenuModelWithData(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("sortField", DEFAULT_SORT_FIELD);
    model.addAttribute("sortDir", DEFAULT_SORT_DIR);
    model.addAttribute("filterCategory", DEFAULT_CATEGRY);
    model.addAttribute("pageSize", DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
    model.addAttribute("filterCategory", DEFAULT_CATEGRY);
    model.addAttribute("order", new OrderCreationDto());
    model.addAttribute("dishList", dishService.findAllDishesSorted(
            DEFAULT_SORT_FIELD, DEFAULT_SORT_DIR));
}
```

Как вы видели, я вывел BindingResult через `System.out.println` и он выглядит так:

> BINDING org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2
> errors

> Field error in object 'orderCreationDto' on field 'address':
> rejected value [ ]; codes
> [NotBlank.orderCreationDto.address,NotBlank.address,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [orderCreationDto.address,address]; arguments []; default
> message [address]]; default message [Address cannot be empty]
>
> Field error in object 'orderCreationDto' on field 'dishIdQuantityMap':
> rejected value [{752=0, 952=0}]; codes
> [HasOrder.orderCreationDto.dishIdQuantityMap,HasOrder.dishIdQuantityMap,HasOrder.java.util.Map,HasOrder];
> arguments
> [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
> codes [orderCreationDto.dishIdQuantityMap,dishIdQuantityMap];
> arguments []; default message [dishIdQuantityMap]]; default message
> [Order does not contain any Dishes]

Пока все хорошо, давайте посмотрим ошибки на странице `menu`..

```
               <p th:text="${#fields.errors()}"></p>
            <p th:text="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}"></p>
```

И мы не видим ничего вообще.

[image]

Я пытался дебажить это всю ночь, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была из-за добавления нового `order` в modal, что сбивало BindingResults.